# example zest layouts

Tags: algorithm, layout, zest

Has anyone created a library of zest layout algorithms other than the ones highlighted here?

http://www.eclipse.org/gef/zest/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some [new algorithms in Zest 2.0](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Zest#New_layout_algorithms), with an overhauled and simplified API for [custom layouts](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Zest#Custom_Layouts).

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is a no.  If anyone finds any would love to hear about it :)